# How do I resolve these missing libraries within netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to setup an existing project within Netbeans. I have some 'missing' libraries displayed in the project properties window shown.

Also, this corresponds to the following entry in the project.properties file

```
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.hibernate-support.classpath}:\
    ${libs.Struts1.2.classpath}:\
    ${libs.ejb3-persistence.classpath}:\
    ${file.reference.activation.jar}:\
```

and the following in the project.xml file

```xml
<web-module-libraries>
                <library dirs="200">
                    <file>${libs.hibernate-support.classpath}</file>
                    <path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>
                </library>
                <library dirs="200">
                    <file>${libs.Struts1.2.classpath}</file>
                    <path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>
                </library>
                <library dirs="200">
                    <file>${libs.ejb3-persistence.classpath}</file>
                    <path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>
                </library>
                <library dirs="200">
                    <file>${file.reference.activation.jar}</file>
                    <path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>
                </library>
```

the activation.jar reference [file.reference.x] is fine, only the references like libs.x.classpath seem to be missing.

I would be grateful for any insight to help with these issues. Thanks

[image: missing libraries]

Comment: add the libraries to the path of your project. or, if it is a maven project, add the correct dependencies to your pom.xml

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are not benefiting from Maven, therefore:

1. <kbd>**Tools**</kbd> » <kbd>**Libraries**</kbd> to open **Ant Library Manager** dialog.

   [image]
2. Create or update the libraries in question.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on dependencies and type the jar file name in the query.
It will list out the jars available for your perusal. Add the required jar library from the list.